# Casting without dongle and multi device "screen sharing"

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast

Since the Chromecast dongle is using a lightweight version of chrome and able to display (cast;-) content from the cloud, would it not make sense that the fuller version of chrome (on windows, Android, and other platforms) would also be able to be a display device?

In other words, it would allow to cast from a smart phone to a tablet, laptop, or anything that runs Chrome.  Simply have these devices added to the list of castable mediums...

Additionally, it looks like a simple and great way to make the technology also support multiple screen sharing...

Comment: I agree that there really needs to be a software version of Chromecast that runs on a computer. My use case is that I aready have a home theater PC under my television. To use the Chromecast I have to switch inputs over to the Chromecast. It would be much better to just google cast to the HTPC.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are confusing chrome the web browser (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) with chrome the operating system (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_OS).

Chromecast as currently available is only good for accepting comands from compatible software (chrome the browser, the youtube app on android or ios etc) at which point it then streams the requested data from the internet, not from your phone/tablet/computer.

Your idea is not supported, which is stunning as Android has had built in support for screen mirroring via miracast since v4.2.
There's also no mention of direct content streaming, for instance via DLNA, an open protocol designed for EXACTLY THAT.
In fact, a better approach here would have been to make the chromecast dongle a DLNA device and then implement support for it on the google play music and youtube ends.

Comment: No confusion at all.  Just saying that the model is that the dongle running a trimmed down version of Chrome picks us the streaming content from the cloud.  So how hard would it be for all Chrome browsers to also pick the content from the web?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/cast/devprev - don't notice that ability off-hand... it mentions having to email mac addresses and websites and things to 'whitelist' for development, if you could just use your browser I wouldn't guess the dev proccess would be so convoluted.